# Как использовать UITapGestureRecognizer в UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, делегаты

Всем привет! Использую такую библиотеку для слайдшоу фотографий и открытия их в полный экран - https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

Проблема заключается в том, что я установил `ImageSlideshow` в `UITableViewCell`:

```
  import ImageSlideshow

  class ImagesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      let imageSlides = ImageSlideshow()
```

Добавляю в него фотографии следующим методом в `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

```
cell.imageSlides.setImageInputs([
            ImageSource(image: self.mainImage!),
            ImageSource(image: self.firstImage!),
            ImageSource(image: self.secondImage!)
            ])
```

Фотографии показываются корректно и тд., но у данной библиотеки есть также возможность открытия каждой этой фотографии в полный экран. Делается это так (далее из документации с GitHub) :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTap))
  slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func didTap() {
  slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
}
```

И вот я на этом запоролся -  не понимаю как добавить `UITapGestureRecognizer` к этому `ImageSlideshow()`, если он находится в `UITableViewCell`, так как в методе `slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)` просит `UIViewController`, когда у меня `UITableViewCell`. Подскажите, пожалуйста -  как добавить `UITapGestureRecognizer` в `UITableViewCell`, чтобы `slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)` срабатывал.

Comment: Добрый день у вас ячейки динамические? Происходит изменение ячеек от времени?

Comment: @ВикторМишустин Да, ячейки динамические.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно запрашивать самый верхний контроллер в ячейке при отрабатывании джестера

Сначала добавьте джестер на view ячейки

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap))
self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

  }
```

Создайте приватный метод для получения `topViewController`

```
private func topMostController() -> UIViewController? {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
      return nil
    }

    var topController = rootViewController

    while let newTopController = topController.presentedViewController {
      topController = newTopController
    }

    return topController
  }
```

Реализуйте ваш метод и кладите в него полученный viewController

```
 @objc func didTap() {
    guard let topVC = topMostController() else { return }
    slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: topVC) 
  }
```

Comment: Благодарю! Ответ правильный.
Только сам джестер я добавлял в методе setSelected.

Comment: Это не очень грамотно, при каждом клике вы создаете новый джестер, они у вас копятся и засоряют память.

Comment: Проблема просто заключается в том, что если я это сделаю в awakeFromNib, то почему-то джестер просто не создается. Как будто бы awakeFromNib просто не вызывается.

Comment: Добавьте сорсы, я посмотрю.

Comment: Все ок, добавил в override init. Огромное спасибо еще раз :)